# Effectively storing and retrieving huge amount of aggregated data for reports

Tags: sql, database, nosql, reporting

The problem is the following. We gather some data in real time, let say 100 entries per second. We want to have real-time reports. The reports should present data by hours. All we want to do is to create some sums of incoming data and have some smart indexing so that we can easily serve queries like "give me value2 for featureA = x, and featureB = y, for 2012-01-01 09:00 - 10:00"

To avoid too many I/O operations we aggregate data in memory (which means we sum them up), then flush them to database. Let us say it happens every 10 seconds or so, which is an acceptable latency for our real-time reports.

So basically, in SQL terms, we end-up with 20 (or more) tables like this (ok, we could have little less of them by combining sum, but it does not make a lot of difference):

1. Time, FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC, value1, value2, valu3
2. Time, FeatureA, FeatureD, value4, value5
3. Time, FeatureC, FeatureE, value6, value7
4. etc.

(I do not say the solution has to be SQL, I only present this to explain the issue at hand.) The Time column is timestamp (with hour precision), Feature columns are some ids of system entities, and values are integer values (counts).

So now the problem arises. Because of the very nature of the data, even if we aggregate them, there are still (too) many inserts to these aggregating tables. This is because some of the data are sparse, which means that for every 100 entries, we have, say, 50 entries to some of aggregating tables. I understand that we can go forward by upgrading the hardware, but what I feel is that we could do better by having smarter storing mechanism. For example, we could use SQL database, but we do not need most of its features (transactions, joins etc.).

So given this scenario my question is the following. How do you guys deal with real-time reporting of high volume traffic? Google somehow does this for web analytics, so it is possible after all. Any secret weapon here? We are open to any solutions - be it Hadoop & Co, NoSQL, clustering or whatever else.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from splitting the storage requirements for collection and reporting/analysis, one of the things we used to do, is look at how often significant changes to a value occurred, and how the data would be used.

No idea what your data looks like, but reporting and analysis is usually looking for significant patterns. In tolerance to out, and vice versa and particularly oscillation.
Now while it's might be laudable to collect an "inifinite" amount of data  just in case you want to analyse it, when you bump into the finite limits of implementing, choices have to be made.

I did this sort of thing in manufacturing environment. We had two levels of analysis. One for control where the granularity was as high as we could afford. Then as the data got further in the past we summarised it for reporting.

I ran into the issues you appear to be more than a few times, and while the loss of data was bemoaned, the complaints about how much it would cost were much louder.

So I wouldn't look at this issue from simply a technical point of view, but from a practical business one. Start from how much the business believes it can afford, and see how much you can give them for it.